# Why doesn't Himawari have a Jougan?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Boruto has a Jougan because his father, Naruto Uzumaki, is a descendant of Hagoromo Otsutsuki, and his mother, Hinata Uzumaki, is a descendant of Hamura Otsutsuki. This gave him Kaguya's chakra and a Jougan (anime only). "Toneri didn't appear in Himawari's dreams and give her a Jougan" isn't the answer I'm looking for, as it is completely wrong. I just want to know why she also didn't get a Jougan as Hagoromo and Hamura's chakra would still mix when she is born, meaning she should have one as well.

Why doesn't she have one? Is it plot hole? Or is a Jougan supposed to be an OP Dojutsu meant for the MC only?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a plot hole or something other than it. It is based on that she is still a child and has to mature in order to learn the techniques and the hidden agendas. Maybe in the future we might see her as a sage with powers comparing to that of Naruto and might even unlock the hidden potential inside of her because her grandpa is a byakugan user and he very much loves his grandchildren. So, we might be in for a treat to witness her greatness and she might spar with her brother in the future since you know, they are siblings with overwhelming powers

Comment: yep you got that.